# UIRefreshControl Crash App Parse.com Query

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uirefreshcontrol

I have a `UICollectionView` with a `UIRefreshControl`. The `UIRefreshControl` runs a query to get objects from Parse.com. When I perform the refresh by "pulling down" it causes the app to crash and display this message:

```
fatal error: Cannot index empty buffer
```

However when I press a button or in the `ViewDidLoad` to run the same refresh code it does not crash and performs the query as required. Does this mean that there is something wrong with the dragging rather than the refresh code?

Here is the refresh code below (is it to do with the positioning of `self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()`?)

```
func refresh(sender:AnyObject)
{

    println("Refresh")

    self.orderedIdArray = []

    self.idArray = []
    self.organizerNameArray = []
    self.categoryNameArray = []
    self.classNameArray = []

    var query = PFQuery(className:"Rides")
    query.orderByAscending("date")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            NSLog("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) scores.")
            // Do something with the found objects


            for object in objects {
                NSLog("%@", object.objectId)

                var testId = object.objectId

                println(testId)


                self.orderedIdArray.append(testId)

                var query = PFQuery(className:"Rides")
                query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(testId) {
                    (gameScore: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

                    if error == nil {



                        NSLog("%@", gameScore)

                        //Gets the Values from Parse.com

                        self.organizerNameString = gameScore["organizer"] as String

                        self.categoryNameString = gameScore["category"] as String

                        self.classNameString = gameScore["class"] as String

                                self.organizerNameArray.append(self.organizerNameString)
                                self.categoryNameArray.append(self.categoryNameString)
                                self.classNameArray.append(self.classNameString)

                                self.idArray.append(object.objectId)
                                NSLog("%@", self.idArray)

                            } else {
                                println("Do not add to the array")

                            }
                    }   
                    } else {
                        NSLog("%@", error)
                    }
                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                }
            }

        } else {
            // Log details of the failure

            NSLog("Error: %@ %@", error, error.userInfo!)

        }
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()

        NSLog("Ordered: %@", self.orderedIdArray)
    }
    println("Completed the query")

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that is executed when the refresh control activates?

Comment: I have added the code above.